# How are dead processes handled by the scheduler in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

I was designing a custom scheduler for linux-6.0.19 version. I am a beginner in Linux kernel development. I tried to implement it and am currently facing a difficulty that I cannot figure out.

I want to know how the usual Linux scheduler integrations deal with dead tasks. The issue which I am facing right now is when a process terminates, the kernel crashes (dereferenced null pointer).

Let us consider the following situation, suppose a process is currently on the corresponding runqueue substructure (of my scheduler) of the actual runqueue. Now, this program terminates. What happens after this?

Some code should possibly set the `p->__state` to `TASK_DEAD` and then is the process dequeued by a call to `dequeue_task`? Or as per the `p->__state`, the necessary `dequeue` of the task shall be done in the `pick_next_task_my_sched` or `put_prev_task_my_sched` accordingly? [If some other section of the kernel actually does the `dequeue`, then our `pick_next_task_my_sched` should not be concerned about picking up a dead-task. Also, `on_rq` shall be set to `0` and `put_prev_task_my_sched` should not be putting it again into the queue.]

In the file `/kernel/sched/core.c` I found the following mention in the function `finish_task_switch`:

> A task struct has one reference for the use as "current". If a task dies, then it sets TASK_DEAD in tsk->state and calls schedule one last time. The schedule call will never return, and the scheduled task must drop that reference.

I am unable to figure out the code flow, which accomplishes this. Can anyone, point me to the code regions which does this part? `Drop that reference` : is the task `dequeued`? Because when I tried to figure out, the code flow, I just saw that certain fields of the `cfs` related data structures were being reset. I did not find an explicit call to `dequeue_task`.

Comment: `exit` is called from userspace to set the task state to TASK_DEAD. Note that this might be normal exit or the default signal handler after a fault. The kernel exit code cleans up the task.